# How to create a TypedColumn in a Spark Dataset and manipulate it?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I'm trying to perform an aggregation using `mapGroups` that returns a SparseMatrix as one of the columns, and sum the columns.

I created a `case class` schema for the mapped rows in order to provide column names. The matrix column is typed `org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Matrix`. If I don't run `toDF` before performing the aggregation (`select(sum("mycolumn")`) I get one type mismatch error (`required: org.apache.spark.sql.TypedColumn[MySchema,?]`). If I include `toDF` I get another type mismatch error: `cannot resolve 'sum(mycolumn)' due to data type mismatch: function sum requires numeric types, not org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.MatrixUDT`. So what's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks you struggle with at least two distinct problems here. Lets assume you have `Dataset` like this:

```
val ds = Seq(
  ("foo",  Matrices.dense(3, 2, Array(1.0, 3.0, 5.0, 2.0, 4.0, 6.0))), 
  ("foo",  Matrices.dense(3, 2, Array(1.0, 3.0, 5.0, 2.0, 4.0, 6.0)))
).toDS
```

Selecting `TypedColumn`:

- using implicit conversions with `$`:

  ```
  ds.select(col("_1").as[String])
  ```
- using `o.a.s.sql.functions.col`:

  ```
  ds.select(col("_1").as[String])
  ```

Adding matrices:

- MLLib `Matrix` and `MatrixUDT` don't implement addition. It means you won't be able to `sum` function or reduce with `+`
- you can use third party linear algebra library but this is not supported in Spark SQL / Spark Dataset

If you really want to do it with `Datsets` you can try to do something like this:

```
ds.groupByKey(_._1).mapGroups(
  (key, values) => {
    val matrices = values.map(_._2.toArray)
    val first = matrices.next
    val sum = matrices.foldLeft(first)(
      (acc, m) => acc.zip(m).map { case (x, y) => x + y }
    )
    (key, sum)
})
```

and map back to matrices but personally I would just convert to RDD and use `breeze`.

Comment: Thanks. Please can you suggest a solution to the addition problem? That's where I'm stuck now.

Comment: Are there matrices dense or sparse? What is the size?

Comment: Fairly small and sparse; small enough to fit on a node.

Comment: Personally I would just convert to RDD and use breeze matrices.